# How to Send Packets to a Remote Minecraft Classic Server in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, minecraft, packets

Hello kind folks of StackOverflow.

I am trying to make a sort of 'bot' which can connect to a Minecraft Classic server, post messages and possibly build.

Anyway, I'm having some trouble understanding how to send packets in python, and how to correctly encode them.

Here are the packets I need to send, I want to send the 'Player Identification' one: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Classic_server_protocol#Client_.E2.86.92_Server_packets
I know I need to be using sockets, and I need to be using struct.pack, but how exactly can I send it?

An example piece code that sends a login packet would be marvellous.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll get the ball rolling:

```
import socket
import struct

username = "username_value"
verification_key = "verification_key"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # boilerplate
s.connect(("example.com", 1234))  # adjust accordingly

# now for the packet
# note that the String type is specified as having a length of 64, we'll pad that

packet = ""

packet += struct.pack("B", 1)  # packet type
packet += struct.pack("B", 7)  # protocol version
packet += "%-64s" % username  # magic!
packet += "%-64s" % verification_key
packet += struct.pack("B", 0)  # that unused byte, assuming a NULL byte here

# send what we've crafted
s.send(packet)
```

The "%-20s" may be weird for you if you've never used format strings. Essentially..

```
print "%s" % 5
```

.. would print out 5 ..

```
print "%10s" % 5
```

.. would pad the output to be exactly 10 characters in width. But it pads them on the right side, we want that padding on the left -- hence the `-` ..

```
print "%-10s" % s, "<this will be 9 spaces away from the '5'>"
```

.. play around with it.

If anything is unclear, let me know. I like what you're doing, reminds me of an old project of mine. Except that I didn't have a neat protocol specification like you did, lucky bastard. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This is exactly what I wanted, couldn't have been more helpful.

Comment: Hello, can you please help me? When i try to connect to MC Classic Server, it gives me error response `Incompatible client, or a network error.`. What should i do?