# Python - Interact with Minecraft Classic server

Tags: python, sockets, bots, minecraft

I am building a simple MinecraftClassic bot in Python. Right now I even can't login. Here is my code so far:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
KEY = "serverkey"
HOST = "68.53.14.13"
PORT = 25566
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
print 'connected'
START_LOGIN = s.sendall(chr(0x00)) # Start login packet
PROTOCOL    = s.sendall(chr(0x07)) # Send protocol version
USERNAME    = s.sendall("Vik2015") # Username
VERKEY      = s.sendall(KEY)       # Verification key
UNUSED      = ""                   # Unused byte
print 'sentall'
print s.recv(4096)
s.close()
```

But when I execute it, my client just sticks forever. It doesn't get any responses from the server. What I am doing wrong? I'd really like to write this bot.

Comment: I assume you have sniffed the traffic to see what it is expecting?

Comment: @cmd, I tried to, but got no results (at least nothing worked). I am using http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Classic_server_protocol now

Comment: Try padding the USERNAME and VERKEY out to 64 characters with spaces.  That doc you linked specifies that strings should be 64 character ASCII padded with spaces.  Also, you have to send the UNUSED byte.

Comment: according to the spec, strings are 64 bytes padded with spaces. "Vik2015" was only a partial string. Once you fix username and validation key, you'll also need to add one more chr at the end for the unused byte.

Comment: @tdelaney, I know that I have to add another, byte. It may sound stupid, but how do I add it? Is it `chr(0x00)` or what?

Comment: @tdelaney, also, about padding. Should I add spaces before or after the username? I mean should it be `"(spaces)username"` or `"username(spaces)"`

Comment: yes, `chr(0x00)` should work, padding could be `"%-64s" % username`

Comment: @Vik2015 - the spec isn't clear - 99% sure the pad is at the end (that's the normal way to do it) but you may have to tweak that.

Comment: @tdelaney, I modified code (as you said), but it isn't working. Client still freezes forever

Comment: you need to actually send that unused byte, `s.sendall(chr(0x00))`

Comment: From looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9521925/600110, it appears that you need to send the `UNUSED` byte, and that null (0x00) is OK.

Comment: @cmd, wow, thanks! I finally got it working. Silly me :) haven't noticed than I am not sending UNUSED byte

Comment: @Vik2015 - um, you needed `s.sendall(chr(0x00))`, not sure why it worked for you. You can send it with far fewer calls by doing: `s.sendall('%c%c%-64s%-64s%c' % (0, 7, USERNAME, KEY, 0))`.

Comment: @tdelaney, I noticed that already. I am finally getting banner from the server :) Now I am going to work on movement

Comment: Also, `sendall` is going to return `None` or raise an exception in all cases, so capturing the result to a variable won't be particularly useful.

Comment: You can find your UUID at namemc.com
Just search up your name and copy the strange random letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the comments together, here's what you get:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
KEY = "ce73007bb263c20268da59eb9fb52b06" # If you want to help me, you can use this key to connect to the server
USERNAME = "Vik2015"
HOST = "68.53.14.13"
PORT = 25566
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
print 'connected'
# login packet (pkt id, protocol version, user name, verification key, pad)
s.sendall('%c%c%-64s%-64s%c' % (0, 7, USERNAME, KEY, 0))
print 'sentall'
print s.recv(4096)
s.close()
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for being so late, but do you have any idea how you get the `KEY`?